# How to prevent peep-dired files processed and listed in recentf list?

Tags: emacs

Emacs Recentf builds a list of recently opened files for easier access later access.  If I use peep-dired to preview files, the recentf list will be flooded with peep-dired list.  Is there a better way to excluded the files if they are from a peep-dired process?

I have tried sth like the following with no luck.

```lisp
(define-globalized-minor-mode my-global-recentf-mode recentf-mode
  (lambda ()
      (unless (or (minibufferp)
          (derived-mode-p 'dired-mode 'peep-dired-mode 'super-save-mode))
          (recentf-mode 1))))
(my-global-recentf-mode 1)
'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following in your [`~/.emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) file, then either type <kbd>M-x eval-buffer</kbd> or restart Emacs:

```
(eval-after-load "peep-dired"
  '(progn
     (defun peep-dired-display-file-other-window--recentf-fix (orig-fun &rest args)
       (let ((recentf-exclude '(".*")))
         (apply orig-fun args)))

     (advice-add 'peep-dired-display-file-other-window :around
                 #'peep-dired-display-file-other-window--recentf-fix)))
```

This code makes sure that `recentf-exclude` is set to match any filename whenever you peep at a file in dired mode.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use option `recentf-exclude` to exclude the files you want to exclude. Just provide a regexp (or a predicate) that matches the directory name, if you want to exclude all files in that directory.

(See also option `recentf-keep`.)

Comment: I am using recentf-exclude.  But it is close to impossible to exclude files during peep-dired session.